# Pass additional parameters to post_save signal

Tags: python, django

I have a user registration form in my Django application which collects additional data while a user is trying to register such as address, city, country, phone number etc.

This data is saved in the Account model class through `post_save` signal. The user creation process goes something like this :

```
# Function to Create user Account/Profile
def create_user_account(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
      models.Account.objects.create(user=instance)

# Create User / User Registration
def UserRegistration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['fn'].capitalize() + ' ' + request.POST['ln'].capitalize()
        # CREATE USER
        newuser = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['pw'])
        newuser.first_name = request.POST['fn'].capitalize()
        newuser.last_name = request.POST['ln'].capitalize()
        newuser.save()
    return HttpResponse(username)

#Post Save handler to create user Account/Profile
post_save.connect(create_user_account, sender=User)
```

Here the `UserRegistration` function is called when a user posts a form and under this function, I can get the POST data, what I want is to pass that data to `create_user_account` method so that it fills in the fields in the `Account` model.

Right now, I do see `Account` objects created in the database, but all the fields except the user field are empty. Obviously, because the POST variables are not being passed to the `create_user_account` method.

Comment: ... but in your example you already store all the information on your user-model ('fn', 'ln') and therefore you should be able to access it via instance.first_name in your `create_user_account` function. Or what am i missing?

Comment: If you want to use some data from POST, you should create `Account` inside the view. Signals is not designed for this.

Comment: @arie There is more data that is not being user in that method yet.

Comment: @astynax thanks, seems like that's how i'll need to do it ..

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What I do is to set some '_attrs' to the instance and then use them in the signal handler.

I imagine your case could be:

```
# Function to Create user Account/Profile
def create_user_account(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        attrs_needed = ['_language', '_field', '_otherfield']
        if all(hasattr(instance, attr) for attr in attr_needed):
            models.Account.objects.create(
                user=instance, 
                language=instance._language, 
                field=instance._field,
                otherfield=instance._otherfield)

# Create User / User Registration
def UserRegistration(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['fn'].capitalize() + ' ' + request.POST['ln'].capitalize()
    # CREATE USER
    newuser = User.objects.create_user(
        username=username, email=request.POST['email'],
        password=request.POST['pw'])
    newuser.first_name = request.POST['fn'].capitalize()
    newuser.last_name = request.POST['ln'].capitalize()

    # Set some extra attrs to the instance to be used in the handler.
    newuser._language = request.POST['language']
    newuser._field = request.POST['field']
    newuser._otherfield = request.POST['otherfield']
    newuser.save()


  return HttpResponse(username)

#Post Save handler to create user Account/Profile
post_save.connect(create_user_account, sender=User)
```

I hate to do this, and I imagine it can breaks in horrible ways, and is hard to debug sometimes, also there is no a strict way to force the data needed for the handler, one could define a `signal_data(data, signal, instance)` to define the data needed for the signal handler for a particular instance.

A nice option that I haven't tried is to use methods of the instance as signal's handlers and maybe we can use a more structured way to pass the data.

Bye.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to this question. Well to overcome this problem i have basically decided to call the Account Model Creation Method inside the View itself as suggested by @astynax

Comment: So like First the User Object is created and Then the User Account in Account Model, both under the same post request..

Comment: I've edited the code since there was an error on it, now I set the attrs before the saving.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  Tried to use this but **newuser._language** is throwing me an error - 'User' object has no attribute '_language'.  Any tips?

Comment: where is the code throwing the exception. Note that there is a check for the existance of the attributes with this line `if all(hasattr(instance, attr) for attr in attr_needed):` this shoul catch any missing attribute and stop the creation of the Account.

Comment: Overrode `if all(hasattr(instance, attr) for attr in attr_needed):` to see what was wrong.  For some reason, the I can't get the custom attribute to stay with the instance.

Comment: My mistake.  I was calling `backend.register()` before `setattr()` without realizing that `register()` calls `save()` on the model.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: For me `User.objects.create_user(` immediately triggers the `post_save` handler. How can I prolong the `post_save` handler so I can set some attributes on the `User` object?

Comment: `User.objects.create(` also triggers the `post_save` immediately. It's critical to solve this somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Both `User.objects.create_user` and `User.objects.create` immediately triggers the `post_save` handler, because the `save` is called in the `UserManager` `create_user`. So I cannot imagine how Jorge's answer can work (at least if you want the save to be triggered only once - why would you trigger it twice???). What you want to do is to look into what `create_user` does, dissect it and this way you can really control when the `save` is called:

```
# Function to Create user Account/Profile
def create_user_account(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        attrs_needed = ['_language', '_field', '_otherfield']
        if all(hasattr(instance, attr) for attr in attr_needed):
            models.Account.objects.create(
                user=instance, 
                language=instance._language, 
                field=instance._field,
                otherfield=instance._otherfield)

# Create User / User Registration
def UserRegistration(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['fn'].capitalize() + ' ' + request.POST['ln'].capitalize()
    # CREATE USER
    newuser = User(
        username=username,
        email=request.POST['email'],
        first_name=request.POST['fn'].capitalize()
        last_name = request.POST['ln'].capitalize()
    )
    newuser.set_password(request.POST['pw'])

    # Set some extra attrs to the instance to be used in the handler.
    newuser._language = request.POST['language']
    newuser._field = request.POST['field']
    newuser._otherfield = request.POST['otherfield']
    newuser.save()  # Now this will be really the first save which is called

  return HttpResponse(username)

#Post Save handler to create user Account/Profile
post_save.connect(create_user_account, sender=User, weak=False)
```

Note that I also use the `weak=False` when I hook up the handler.

Comment: This answer should work. The approved answer is wrong as the explanation in this answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that `receiver(post_save, sender=User)` is called immediately when we use `create_user` and `create` method,
So, we need to initialize the object firstly, then fill the extra field.