# Django admin command and sending custom arguments to post_save signal

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

This is my first project in Django and I'm trying to write a user import script as a part of an admin command, through manage.py. I'm having a bit of trouble because I want to read user data from another table and get_or_create users based on email. This is the simple part. I also have a user profile model, that I am using for all other "profile" data.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to set up my signal to receive my profile information and fill my profile table with data. I've gotten to the point where empty profile rows are being created, but I want the rows to be filled. Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

I have referenced these links so far with no luck:

[Pass additional parameters to post_save signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179380/pass-additional-parameters-to-post-save-signal)

https://coderwall.com/p/ktdb3g/django-signals-an-extremely-simplified-explanation-for-beginners

---

**load_users.py**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from subscriber_conf.models import ActiveSubscriber
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from subscriber_conf import signals

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Command(BaseCommand):
   help = 'Imports user records'

   def handle(self, *args, **options):

      subscriber = ActiveSubscriber.objects.get(pk=10037)

      logger.debug("running user import........")
      u = User.objects.create_user(username=subscriber.email, email=subscriber.email, 
        first_name=subscriber.first_name, last_name=subscriber.last_name,
        password='mypass')

      #....add more data to send to signal....
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from subscriber_conf.models import Profile
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def insert_profile(sender, **kwargs):

   logger.debug("Post_save: insert_profile running.......")
   instance = kwargs.get('instance')

   if created:
     Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

Comment: where does the extra data come from? you can't add extra  data to the `post_save` signal... you could use a custom signal, but that only makes sense if there's more than one place in the code where you are creating `User`s and have the extra data available, otherwise just put the profile creating code in your command (or nicer: pull the code from your command into a standalone function and call it from the command)

Comment: This is a good answer. I'll try it out. I just thought signals was the 'right' way to do it, since all the documentation points to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem with help from @Anentropic. I simply got rid of my signal code and added my profile create to the admin command. Simple and works as I want.

**loadusers.py**

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from subscriber_conf.models import ActiveSubscriber
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from subscriber_conf import signals
from subscriber_conf.models import Profile

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Imports user records'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        subscriber = ActiveSubscriber.objects.get(pk=10037)

        logger.debug("running user import........")
        u = User.objects.create_user(username=subscribers.email, email=subscriber.email, 
            first_name=subscriber.first_name, last_name=subscriber.last_name,
            password='KgLTLgLXQM6oXNfEbEfvb8ya')

        zippy = all_subscribers.full_zip
        tmp_zip = zippy.split("-")
        new_zip = tmp_zip[0]

        Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=u,
            street_address1=subscriber.street_address1, street_address2=subscriber.street_address2,
            city=subscriber.city, state=subscriber.state, full_zip=subscriber.full_zip,
            zip_code=new_zip, account_updated=1, phone_number=subscriber.phone_number)
```