# how to send email confirmation mail, after post_save signal with djanago-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, django-signals

I am using `django-allauth` in my webapp for account management.

I have User model and UserProfile Model.

When User gets signs up it creates a user(an instance in user model).

UserProfile is assosiated with model User.

Allauth by default sends an email when user signs Up,A confirmation email will be sent to user when he signs up.

Now I want to send that email only when  he fills UserProfile.

I am thiking to use signals here.
When user fill UserProfile, it will call post_save signal , which calls another function `user_signed_up_` but I am facing problem in passing request and user args to that function.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from allauth.account.signals import user_signed_up
from allauth.account.utils import send_email_confirmation
from django.dispatch import receiver
import datetime

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    are_u_intrested = models.BooleanField(default=False)


#this signal will be called when user signs up.allauth will send this signal.

@receiver(user_signed_up, dispatch_uid="some.unique.string.id.for.allauth.user_signed_up")
def user_signed_up_(request, user, **kwargs):

    send_email_confirmation(request, user, signup=True)
    #this allauth util method, which sends confirmation email to user.





models.signals.post_save.connect(user_signed_up_, sender=UserProfile, dispatch_uid="update_stock_count")

#If user fills this userProfile , then I only send confirmation mail.
#If UserProfile model instace saved , then it send post_save signal.
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `django-allauth`, but if there is `post_save` - why do you need pass user arg? - you can get it using `instance.user` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: Actually I need request object also.

Comment: then you must find another way, or you have to change `instance` before signal handler and add to it some `_attrs` that you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/11388127/3033586

Comment: if request object is needed by the receiver, then you may have to send a custom signal from somewhere like `form.save` method, and add `request` when dispatching the signal, like `def send_signal(self, request):
        user_reg.send(sender=self.__class__, request=request)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to be using allauth's signals here, you need to be using Django's model signals. Something like:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=UserProfile)
def userprofile_filled_out(sender, instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
    # Don't want to send it on creation or raw most likely 
    if created or raw:
        return

    # Test for existence of fields we want to be populated before
    # sending the email
    if instance.field_we_want_populated:
       send_mail(...)
```

Hope that helps!