# How should I register a new user(custom) in django rest framework?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

When ever I create a new User, the corresponding    `BaseUser` is not getting created. The signal is working correctly as I have checked without the attributes     `department` and     `user_type` how do I go about registering the     `BaseUser`?

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class BaseUser(models.Model):
   # TODO: Add a class with static method to return the list of departments(choices)
   # TODO: (REMINDER) To add placeholder that username is rollnumber

USER_TYPES = (
        (0, 'Student'),
        (1, 'Professor'),
        (2, 'Guest'),
)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True,
        related_name='user')
department = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='CSE')
user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPES, default=0)

REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'department',
        'email',
        'first_name',
        'user_type'
]

def get_user_type(self):
    return self.USER_TYPES[self.user_type][1]

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(
            dict((
                self.user.user_name,
                self.get_user_type(),
                ))
            )

# serializers.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework import serializers

from authentication.models import BaseUser


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'email'
        )

class BaseUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    user_type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = BaseUser
        fields = (
            'user',
            'user_type',
            'department',
        )

    def get_user_type(self, obj):
        return obj.get_user_type()

# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route, list_route

from authentication.models import BaseUser
from authentication.serializers import BaseUserSerializer, UserSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

**EDIT:** I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179380/pass-additional-parameters-to-post-save-signal) approach, but I got an error that User doesn't have those attributes(i.e `'Some fields are empty!'`

```
# signals.py
# I have another signal in signals.py and it is working fine.
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        attrs_needed = ['department', 'user_type']
        if all(hasattr(instance, attr) for attr in attrs_needed):
            base_user = BaseUser(
                    user=instance,
                    department=instance.department,
                    user_type=instance.user_type,
            )
            base_user.save()
        else:
            print "Some fields are empty!"
# views
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @list_route(methods=['post'])
    def create_baseuser(self, request):
        print request.DATA['username']
        user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=request.DATA['username'],
                password=request.DATA['password'],
                email=request.DATA['email'],
                first_name=request.DATA['first_name']
        )

        user.department = request.DATA['department']
        user.user_type = request.DATA['user_type']

        user.save()
        return Response(data='{"detail":"created"')
```

Comment: I don't see any code that would create the base user in the non-DRF case...  is this currently happening for you?  For example if you use the manage.py command to create a user

Comment: No it doesn't.  Could you suggest any other way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all users are going to have these types I'd just suggest extending with a custom user model for less serializer related headaches (especially if you want to be able to just POST/PUT to /user/  to change these fields and don't want to go through the exercise of extending your serializers)   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

But if it's not working on your script either...  maybe your signal isn't set up right?  I don't see any post_save signal in your original code

Comment: I don't think that will work because the signal won't have department & user type as the actual model definition does not...

Comment: Yet another solution would be to extend perform_create of the ModelSerializer in BaseUserSerializer to split it to create two models.  But if you want all users to have these fields might as well just extend the user model

Comment: 'extend the user model' - do you mean extending `AbstractBaseUser`?

Comment: Yes, or AbstractUser (if you want to keep all the default behaviour + extend it)

It'll save you from wrangling with getting a serializer to write to two places as well (for ex. if you want to update both type & email through a REST call)

Comment: Yeah, I think I have to go with inheriting `AbstractBaseUser`. Thanks for your help!