# How do I pass instance in models within signals?

Tags: python, django, signals

I have the following model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    education = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    facebook = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    whatsapp = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

I am creating a signal that after saving user, it creates a profile associated to that, the code below is my signal. I don't know how to pass `instance` in `Profile.objects.create`. I muse that passing instance like `instance.education`, `instance.country` ... is wrong or there are other errors in this signal because I am getting this error `User has no profile`. Please help me fix it, thank you

`signals.py`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print("INSTANCE BELOW:")
    print(instance)
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance, education=instance.education,
                               country=instance.country, facebook=instance.facebook,
                               whatsapp=instance.whatsapp, description=instance.description)
```

Comment: you just want to create a blank profile (since you don't have the values for `education` etc... yet). So just `Profile.objects.create(user=instance)` will do what you want.

Comment: The question is whether is makes sense to do that, you can also create the `Profile` when the user actually goes to his profile page to fill in the various fields for the profile. But that's up to you. There are pros to always having a profile object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass additional parameters to post\_save signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179380/pass-additional-parameters-to-post-save-signal)